# How is it possible to open your glider without using a launch pad?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I just ended a game Soaring 50's in Fortnite. I was shooting the ramp that a team mate was running on so he would fall and get knocked down. But out of nowhere he opened his glider and just flew away while he didn't reach the launch pad he was going for.

So my question is: How can you open your glider without even using a launch pad or another tool?

Comment: Nothing to do with post: BTW, you might get banned if you repeatly team kill.

Comment: I don't do it as often as you'd think. It is just a couple of times. I'm mostly out there killing players on my own.

Comment: I do that sometimes too. But dont do it too often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a part of the new game mode you mentioned, Soaring 50's. I have yet to play it myself, but [IGN has posted an article](http://www.ign.com/articles/2018/08/15/fortnite-gets-new-soaring-50s-mode) about it. The first paragraph has the information you're looking for.

> First up is Soaring 50's, which adds a new dimension to Fortnite's 50
>   vs. 50 mode by letting players glide all over the map. Instead of only
>   being able to use gliders at the start of matches and by using special
>   items, but Soaring 50's grants the ability to deploy gliders whenever
>   a player jumps or falls from a significant height.

Comment: Oh yeah,  I just found it. Thanks for your answer by the way.